# Notepadd++ Python Script: Delete everything between the last 3 " - " if line starts with X

Tags: python, notepad++

Looking at the end of the line counting the " - " backwards (notice the spaces) and delete the text but only if the line starts with fx TEST.

Before

```
TESTMouse - Dog - CAT - Fish
Mouse - Dog - CAT - Fish
TESTRat - Whale - Bird - Horse - Snake
```

After

```
TESTMouse
Mouse - Dog - CAT - Fish
TESTRat - Whale
```

This is beyond my ability to write myself and I have not found anything that would work in my searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No needs for Notepad++ PythonScript, a simple find and replace is enough:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^TEST.*?\K(?: - \w+){3}$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    TEST        # literally
    .*?         # 0 or more any character, not greedy
    \K          # forget all we have seen until this position
    (?:         # non capture group
        - \w+      # space, hyphen, space, 1 or more word character
    ){3}        # end group, must appear 3 times
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This works greats expect that () [] and <> breaks it. Could that be prevented somehow? I made a simplified explanation of what I thought was difficult and it excluded that info when I shouldn't have.

Comment: @Aceofrogues: Do you mean you may have some special characters? In this case, instead of `\w+`, use `[^-\r\n]+` or `(?:(?! - ).)+`

Comment: Yes I have some special characters in there. Using [^-\r\n]+ instead of \w+ worked perfectly. Again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple answer using Pythons [string](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_string.asp) functions, probably could get a bit shorter of an answer with [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Please test it and tell me if you have any issues.

```
with open("testfile.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open("testfile.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        # strip trailing newline
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if line.startswith("TEST"):
            # split line into parts from ' - '
            parts = line.split(' - ')
            # keep first 3 parts
            if len(parts) > 3:
                line = ' - '.join(parts[:-3])
        f.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm afraid I made a mistake and out of ignorance said Python when i should have used Regex. I'll repost the question with this correction but leave this up so others can find it.

Comment: So do you want to use regex where exactly, or run the script how? Do you mean a regex in the notepadd++ search and replace or?

Comment: Again so thankful for you helping and so sorry for not knowing the right words.

I'm doing many FX editor.rereplace and saving them as a script so i can run them easier. So if it could be something that could fit there that would be great.

Comment: Alright, then the answer below from toto should work as intended